# Updating the Model and then Getting a Document Element

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do the following:

```
vm.request.StatusDescription = 'In Progress';

var contents = $document[0].getElementById(elementId).innerHTML;
```

The contents I get from the DOM, within the requested element, contain a binding for `{{ vm.request.StatusDescription }}`, but when I use the HTML contents in a new window (intended for printing a subset of the screen), the status description hasn't updated.  It still reads 'New'.

Is there any simple way to deal with this?  I've looked at using `$scope.$apply();` with no success.

Comment: Is your vm variable attached to $scope?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle of this? If you had the working code we could see exactly what you wish to do. Looks like you are doing things like you used to do in jquery not how it should be done in angularjs.

Comment: @MorganPolotan I have `var vm = this;` earlier in the controller, I don't know if that helps.

Comment: @aCa that's the heart of my question really, I'm not so much manipulating the DOM, just reading from it (I thought using $document instead of document might help).  I'm looking for a good AngularJS solution.

Comment: Ok tried to give you an answer, but kinda hard without  you providing a jsfiddle to show exactly what you try to achieve

Comment: You shouldn't need to do `$scope.$apply()` in a controller because a `$digest` loop will already be in progress. The Angular way to read/manipulate the DOM is through directives.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example  on how to update an value in AngularJS. You can then read from $scopeStatusDescription where you need the current status in your controller or in your view.

```
$scope.StatusDescription = 'New';

$timeout(function() {
    $scope.StatusDescription = 'In Progress';
}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NBhn4/101/